# How do I pass dropdown values via JSON record response to react UI?

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, spring-boot, dropdown

I need to get feedback on the preferred method of architecting a JSON response to not only provide data elements but also control the UI elements as well (specifically select boxes)

I am currently designing a suite of REST services to support a new application.  All data will be served from the REST services and the frontend will be Spring-Boot/REACT.js.

We want all business logic to be managed at the data layer (Spring-Boot MicroServices).  So all of the "select options" (dropdowns) will be driven by data provided by the Java Service via the RESTful services.

I am just looking for feedback on either of these options (or if you have a more preferred option, please feel free.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Curry",
    "last_name": "Aburrow",
    "email": "caburrow0@gnu.org",
    "gender": "Male",
    "gender_options": {
        "0":"Male",
        "1":"Female"
        }
    "department": "Sales"
    "department_options": {
        "0":"Sales",
        "1":"Legal",
        "2":"HR",
        "3":"Finance",
        "4":"Operations"
        }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Joachim",
    "last_name": "Lotte",
    "email": "jlotte1@webnode.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "gender_options": {
        "0":"Male",
        "1":"Female"
        }
    "department": "Finance"
    "department_options": {
        "0":"Sales",
        "1":"Legal",
        "2":"HR",
        "3":"Finance",
        "4":"Operations"
        }
  }
]
```

OR THIS

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Curry",
    "last_name": "Aburrow",
    "email": "caburrow0@gnu.org",
    "gender": {
        "selected":"Male",
        "options": {
            "0":"Male",
            "1":"Female"
            }
    "department": {
        "selected":"Sales",
        "options": {
        "0":"Sales",
        "1":"Legal",
        "2":"HR",
        "3":"Finance",
        "4":"Operations"
        }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Joachim",
    "last_name": "Lotte",
    "email": "jlotte1@webnode.com",
    "gender": {
        "selected":"Female",
        "options": {
            "0":"Male",
            "1":"Female"
            }
    "department": {
        "selected":"Finance",
        "options": {
        "0":"Sales",
        "1":"Legal",
        "2":"HR",
        "3":"Finance",
        "4":"Operations"
        }
  }
]
```

Option 1 is basic json providing the select option array in it's own element. 
Option 2 is nested array.

Neither of which is overly complex, just looking for the more performant method.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that department options and gender options should not be a part of the Object in the first place. Those should come from a separate json which can be either static or is configurable by some CMS. So you should just be fine with this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Curry",
    "last_name": "Aburrow",
    "email": "caburrow0@gnu.org",
    "gender": "Male",
    "department": "Sales"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Joachim",
    "last_name": "Lotte",
    "email": "jlotte1@webnode.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "department": "Finance"
  }
]
```

Also, your gender options and department options aren't really arrays. They're Objects. You can either make them string arrays or better, make them object arrays so that they could also have something like a `display` and `value` field that could then be used. For eg:

For gender options:

```
[{
    display: "Male",
    value: "MALE"
  },
  {
    display: "Female",
    value: "FEMALE"
  }
]
```

For department options:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    display: "Sales",
    value: "SALES"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    display: "Legal",
    value: "LEGAL"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    display: "HR",
    value: "HR"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    display: "Finance",
    value: "FINANCE"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    display: "Operations",
    value: "OPERATIONS"
  }
]
```

Comment: My fault, yes they are objects, and should be arrays.

The LOV's must be part of the data response for two reasons.

1: We are building a service based application that needs to feel extremely light weight.  Network transactions (data calls) will be our heaviest function. 

2: All of our business logic must reside in the service layer. So "conditional" LOV's must be represented in the response unfortunately.

Not sure if nested or a separate element works best.